# Get all data associated with an identifier from SQL table

Tags: php, sql

This function should get all data from an SQL table associated with the id of the current document and the meta_key mentioned.

```
<?php

$post_id = $post->ID;
$pics = mysql_query("SELECT    %$post_id%, 
           meta_wp_attached_file.meta_value pictures

FROM      wp_postmeta meta_wp_attached_file
 ON        meta_wp_attached_file.post_id = '%$post_id%'

 WHERE     meta_wp_attached_file.meta_key = 'picture' 

    ORDER BY picture");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($lpics)) {
    $thumb = $row['picture'];
    echo '<img src="http://www.golfbrowser.com/wp-content/uploads/'.$thumb.'" />';

}
```

?>

So the ID is mentioned on the page and used under $post_id. The meta_key we want is called `_wp_attached_file` and we want to echo the value inside an image.

Any ideas?

Marvellous

Comment: AFAIK `ON` keyword used with `JOIN` , but there is no `JOIN` syntax in your query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this: 
in your query replace ON with WHERE and WHERE with AND

Comment: I think this is a good start, but I can't understand the goal of the OPs question.